# Can 'Alas' be used ironically in the following statement

Tags: word-choice, expressions, irony, emotions

Alas! Torm makes a polar voyage to explore the arctic Canada.
Alas! Torm indeed makes the Voyage across Arctic Canada exploring the unexplored, and how does she do it? In style. Always in style!!

-Note: Torm has never made an arctic voyage before and this particular voyage turned out to be a spectacular one.

Comment: If you don't begrudge this person's feat deep down but are rather happy instead, then it's tantamount to saying-- Alas! I have hit the jackpot.

Comment: Using it in that context doesn’t make much sense to me.  Unless you were trying to do it first but Torm beat you ’to it.  Then *alas* might be reasonable. Or maybe you were betting she wouldn’t go through with it.

Comment: Not 'the arctic Canada'. Either 'Arctic Canada' or 'the Canadian Arctic'. We capitalise Arctic when using it geographically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is "verbal irony"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/what-exactly-is-verbal-irony) Anything *can* be used as irony. Whether you want to do so or not is just a matter of personal opinion. If you think *alas* shouldn't be, explain you're reasoning.

Comment: Are you sure that understand [alas](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alas#:~:text=(Entry%201%20of%202),Alas) correctly? Merriam Webster, for example, defines it as **used to express unhappines, pity or concern** with the example **Alas life is too short**