# Reversal of Meaning

Tags: meaning

I’m searching for the term whereby the intended use of a word is  opposite to its established meaning.

‘Doublespeak’ is not quite it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example or two of what you mean?

Comment: There _is_ the sarcastic or ironic use of a word, when a person cruelly says say "That was really _good_" but means the opposite. But that's well covered at [What exactly _is_ verbal irony?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/what-exactly-is-verbal-irony).

Comment: Sarcasm/irony might be the root of something like *wicked* or *sick* for "really good" but it's more likely to be young people's delight in perverse difference. An example or two in the question would be really helpful.

Comment: I once heard a young lady describe a young gentleman as “so cool he’s hot”.